# C# Xml in Http Post Request Message Body

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am looking for an example of how, in C#, to put a xml document in the message body of a http request and then parse the response. I've read the documentation but I would just like to see an example if there's one available. Does anyone have a example?

thanks

Answer (score 31):

```
private static string WebRequestPostData(string url, string postData)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

    req.ContentType = "text/xml";
    req.Method = "POST";

    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
    {
        if (resp == null) return null;

        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `WebRequest` class.

There is an annotated sample available here to send data:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx