# Problems with C# HTTP Post with Authentication

Tags: c#, http, authentication

I'm trying to send some XML through HTTP Post. But I'm getting `401 Unauthorized`. Funny thing is when I access the URL through the browser, the username/password I provide are OK.

Here is my method signature:

```
        internal static string Send(string URL, string XMLdata, string RequestMethod, 
                                    string RequestUsername, string RequestPassword)
```

I have tried this as method body:

```
        string requestData = XMLdata;
        string responseData = "";

        StreamWriter myWriter = null;
        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

        objRequest.Method = RequestMethod;
        objRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";//"text/xml";
        objRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(RequestUsername, RequestPassword);;
        objRequest.ContentLength = requestData.Length;

        try
        {
            myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream());
            myWriter.Write(requestData);
        }
        finally
        {
            myWriter.Close();
        }

        StreamReader sr = null;

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
            sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
            responseData = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sr != null)
                sr.Close();
        }

        return responseData;
```

And also this:

```
        string result;

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            Uri requestUri = new Uri(URL);
            CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(RequestUsername, RequestPassword);
            cache.Add(requestUri, "Basic", nc);
            client.Credentials = cache;

            result = client.UploadString(requestUri, XMLdata);
        }

        return result;
```

Both get the `401`. What am I doing wrong? Just a reminder: when I access the URL through the browser, it prompts for username/password and the credentials I provide are OK.

My readings on the subject so far:

- [HttpClient and forms authentication in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640116/http-client-authentication-c)
- [Login to the page with HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450380/login-to-the-page-with-httpwebrequest)
- [HTTP POST Returns Error: 417 "Expectation Failed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566437/http-post-returns-the-error-417-expectation-failed-c)
- [HTTP Post XML document - server receives only first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992110/http-post-xml-document-server-receives-only-first-line)
- [POST to HTTPS authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380010/post-to-https-authentication-error)
- [C# Xml in Http Post Request Message Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716024/c-xml-in-http-post-request-message-body)

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Maybe the authentication type is NTLM?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, from your description, but I do have a suggestion: use Fiddler to see what the request and response look like, both when the browser request succeeds, and when the programmatic request fails. I suspect there will be a difference that jumps out at you.

Comment: "it prompts for username/password" - in a popup window? Then it is Win auth.

Comment: Yes, it prompts in a browser popup window, no matter what browser. Are you sure that makes this a Windows Authentication? Either way, do you know what I change in the codes I posted?

Comment: @jwismar Great tip, will do and let you know the outcome. BTW, you should post that as an answer

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/3ae9753d-2d97-45b9-9ba2-6d551fe60a48 "After a client request to a specific Uri is successfully authenticated. This means that the 1st time you send an HTTP request to a specific Uri, it is intentional that the request won't have an Authorization header."

Comment: @Adrian: You're right, BASIC authentication pops up a message box, too.

Comment: @Tomas: In .Net, the HttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate property can be set so that even the first request sends credentials; I use that in cases where I know in advance I'm going to be sending the credentials anyway.

Comment: @jwismar Can you share more specific info? Read http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Feb/18/NET-WebRequestPreAuthenticate-not-quite-what-it-sounds-like, i've experienced same. But if you know more, i will be happy to know other ways.

Comment: @Tomas: Interesting. I'm not using BASIC auth right now, so can't run a test, but I thought I recalled that it worked as advertised, and didn't recall the wrinkle that's described there. From that writeup, it still sounds like a valuable property to keep in mind, in terms of lessening the overall round-trips.

Comment: I got it! I posted an answer below and thank everyone for taking the time to look at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Actually I was misled by the provider to make a mistake with the URL. The reason I'm posting my answer is for future reference, if someone ever comes across this.

The provider emailed me with the URL `http://api.providersurl.com`. When I get that into browser, it gets redirected to `https://api.providersurl.com` (HTTPS!). Then, I'm able to authorize with the credentials.

The funny thing that kept me banging my head against the wall is that by accessing the HTTP URL, I did not get `404 (Not Found)` nor `302 (Redirect)`. I got `401 (Unauthorized)`. So I just kept trying! And boy, did I try...

When I changed the URL in the code to HTTPS, authorization worked with BOTH codes I posted.

It took a few hours... But no time is waste of time when you are learning a getting experienced.

Answer (score 1):

[At request of OP, I'm migrating my comment to an answer]

I don't have an answer for you, from your description, but I do have a suggestion: use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what the request and response look like, both when the browser request succeeds, and when the programmatic request fails. I suspect there will be a difference that jumps out at you.

Comment: I can tell you, as useful as this hint mat have been, what a pain debugging messages is! So far, have not discovered it yet...